# set DATE_PIPE_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE with useFactory

Tags: angular, angular-date-format

I am trying to set custom timezone via `useFactory` that causing an error that timeZone.replace is not a function. But with `useValue` it is working fine.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class Foo {
  bar() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('-0400');
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: DATE_PIPE_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE,
      deps: [Foo],
      // useValue: '-0400',
      useFactory: async (foo: Foo) => {
        return foo.bar();
      },
    },
  ],
```

See the app.module.ts
Playground: [angular default timezone stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jmvb7n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Did you resolve this? I've got the same issue.

Comment: You will have to do it like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zduvzu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts